# How install PIP & PYMSSQL in docker

Tags: python, docker, azure-aks

I have a Python program which is to be executed in the Azure Kubernetes.

Below is my docker file - I have Python installed

```
#Ubuntu Base image with openjdk8 with TomEE

FROM demo.azurecr.io/ubuntu/tomee/openjdk8:8.0.x

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet && apt-get install -y ksh && apt-get install -y python2.7.x && apt-get -y clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

however I don't know how to install PIP and related dependent libraries (eg: pymssql)?

Comment: If you start your image `FROM python:3.9`, the [Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) includes `pip`, and then you can `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` to include your Python library dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use python 2.7.5, please suggest.

Comment: Python 2.7 is over a decade old, and a year and a half ago the Python team made [the last Python 2.x release ever](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).  I'd highly recommend updating your application to a supported language version.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is installing miniconda on docker image. I used it always when I need to have python on docker image without python or pip.

Here is part for installing minicinda in my simple docker image

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN conda --version
```

Comment: A have added part of `Dockerfile` with miniconda installation

Comment: Thank you, does it need any license for production usage? does it support Python 2.7.5?

Comment: I used it only for local solutions, I think you can use commercial (but please check these -- i'm not good in license topic). Yes you can configure env with python 2.7.